# Closing many gnuplot -persist windows

Tags: x11, kill, gnuplot

I just opened more than a hundred persistent graphing windows using `gnuplot -persist` with `x11` on a RHEL desktop. Is there any easy way to close them all? I don't really want to logout/in or click through them manually.

Answer (score 1):

To kill all Gnuplot processes:

```
pkill -x gnuplot
```

If you want to kill just the Gnuplot processes that were invoked with the `-persist` option:

```
pkill -fx 'gnuplot -persist.*'
```

If you want to close the windows without closing the Gnuplot processes (I think that's useless here because closing the windows causes the Gnuplot processes to exit), you can use [`wmctrl`](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo/wmctrl/): `wmctrl -c gnuplot` closes all Gnuplot windows (more precisely, it sends a `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` message to all windows whose title contains `gnuplot`, which is the same as clicking the “close” button on all these windows). If you want to close only some of the Gnuplot windows, you can parse the output of `wmctrl -l` to find the window IDs that you want and close the windows with `wmctrl -c` or `xkill -id`.